# The type or namespace name could not be found. SeleniumBasicAuthWrapper

Tags: c#, nuget, build-error

I have created unit test project in VS12 and installed package 'SeleniumBasicAuthWrapper' from NuGet.
When I add

```
using SeleniumBasicAuth;
```

and try to build project I get following error message:

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'SeleniumBasicAuth' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is it in your references? NuGet should have added it there, but please check and make sure.

Comment: Are you sure your package installed correctly?

Comment: @dhicock yes, it is.

It's very weird because, when I create objects from this package, ReSharper proposes to add reference automatically. But when I build the project it fails with error.

Comment: @SonerGönül I am not. But I have tried several times on two different computers. Installed it in completely new projects, same thing.

Comment: Does the package support the version of .NET your project is in?

Comment: @dhicock yes it is - 4.5.1 and 4.5.1 installed!